# Hamburger in desktop-first site

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, hamburger-menu

I want to display hamburger icon and list items in it only on mobile view and want no menu items in navbar in the desktop and tablet view. How do i achieve this if possible with bootstrap or otherwise? This is kind of what i want to do but with a better method if possible.

https://aanchalch.github.io/jhu-assignment-3/

Answer (score 1):

Use media queries: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/CSS_Media_queries

```
// indicate for mobile sizes
@media screen and (min-width: 576px) {
  // your css here
}

// indicate for desktop
@media screen and (min-width: 992px) {
  // your css here
}
```

check the right values on bootstrap doc
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#grid-options

Answer (score 0):

## Hello Dear!

This is Bootstrap 4.5  No need to use @media query for that

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>

<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-12">
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Dropdown
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
      <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</nav>
</div>
</div>
</div>

    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

## Try to use this

Comment: i dont want menu items in my navbar for the desktop or tablet view at all. i only need the hamburger and list items in it for the mobile view. for the desktop view i just want the logo  of the brand.

Comment: Greate ! man

Please use this in your html page and see the result .

Comment: What i mean is I don't need the ul (from your exmaple) **at all** in the desktop or tablet view. I only want there to be an ul in the mobile view when i click on the hamburger. Please see this https://aanchalch.github.io/jhu-assignment-3/ This is kind of what I wanted to do but needed to know if there a better way to do that.